# C fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory #include <Python.h>

Tags: python, c, numpy

I am running Python within C, and I can't seem to get the program to compile. I have the following included in the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glib.h>

#include <Python.h>
#include <arrayobject.h>
```

I am working in VS Code and I have the following `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-I/usr/include/**",
                "-I~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/include/python3.9/**",
                "-I~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/**",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

When I compile, I get an error:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always -I/usr/include/** -I~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/include/python3.9/** -I~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/** -g ~/Documents/code/test.c -o ~/Documents/code/test
~/Documents/code/test.c:6:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <Python.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

I thought that with the `-I` statements, I'd included everything necessary to run this. What is the best way to include the necessary files? By the way, I also get errors with `#include <glib.h>`, which should be included with `-I/usr/include/**`. I'm pretty new to `C` so I apologize if this is an obvious question.

Comment: What shell are you using? `-I/usr/include/**` should perhaps be `-I /usr/include/**` but you should have `-I` infront of all directories.

Comment: What do you get with `find /usr/include/ |grep -i python.h` ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I made those changes and I'm getting the same errors

Comment: @Ôrel the command `find /usr/include/ | grep -i python.h` yields no results. Same for `find /usr/include/** | grep -i python.h`.

Comment: And `find ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/include/python3.9 -type f | grep -i python.h` ?

Comment: the command `find ~/anaconda3/envs/metagenomics/include/python3.9/ -type f | grep -i python.h` yields a result: `~anaconda3/envs/myenv/include/python3.9/Python.h`

Comment: That tells you where you need your `-I` to point to.

Comment: BTW, `-I` doesn't work with wildcards or tildes. Use `-I"$HOME/..."`, not `-I~/...`

Comment: I thought `-I` needed to point to a directory, in which case (not using tides, thank you!), the command is: `/usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always "-I /usr/include/**" "-I $HOME/anaconda3/envs/myenv/include/python3.9/**" "-I $HOME/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/**" -g $HOME/Documents/git/resist/code/test.c -o $HOME/Documents/git/resist/code/test`. This yields the same error.

Comment: @CopyOfA `**` is expanded by the shell - if you have a shell capable of expanding it. `-I something/**` will expand to all files and directories in `something`. You need one `-I` before each directory as I mentioned. What you show above does not have that. Since `**` also shows all files, you'll potentially have a lot of irrelevant arguments. You can't use `"-I something/**"` though. That is not expanded.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using **pkg-config**

```
"args": [
  "pkg-config --cflags python3",
}
```

Comment: How should I tie this to my `anaconda` virtual environment?

Comment: Does Anaconda set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Anaconda, but you can check where pkg-config searches for installed libraries `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config` and if you want to set value `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/my/path` should do.

Comment: Can you use it just like that? Will it actually execute `pkg-config` when you list it in `args`? I would expect something like `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs python3)` to pass it on to the shell ... but, even that feels a bit fragile.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good point. Probably adding backticks should do the job as well.

Comment: @David Yes. If `$(...)` works, I assume that backticks will too.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as an answer, though credit goes to the several contributors here. The trick is to include each folder you need individually. So my new `tasks.json` file is:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [

                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-I/usr/include/glib-2.0",
                "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                "-I$HOME/anaconda3/envs/myenv/include/python3.9",
                "-I$HOME/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```